# Determine Wi-Fi availability in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-wifi, wifimanager

When attempting to determine if Wi-fi is even available, my app crashes.

I have a try/catch block surrounding

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

but it's mere presence crashes the app with a null pointer exception.

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

How does one determine if wi-fi is even available otherwise?

**EDIT**

Stack Trace:

```
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.myapp.ui.FragmentSettingsDetailWireless.loadControls(FragmentSettingsDetailWireless.jav   a:121)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.myapp.ui.FragmentSettingsDetailWireless.onActivityCreated(FragmentSettingsDetailWireles    s.java:110)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:814)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-08 20:10:21.820: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**The activity variable was NULL.  Mea Culpa!**

Comment: have you initiated your activity? that seems to be the only thing that can throw a null pointer in this line of code...

Comment: I am pretty sure the fragment would not exist w/o the activity existing first.  If your wondering whether the activity reference is null, then no - that gets set when the fragment attaches.

Comment: right. can you debug and tell us what throws the null pointer? or attach a log with stacktrace?

Comment: make sure your fragment is attached to an activity before calling this since getActivity() will return null until then.

Comment: Please post all of you logcat errors and tell us which line number the code above is.

Comment: Thanks, what is line 121 in `FragmentSettingsDetailWireless.java`?

Comment: Line 121 is:  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: A NullPointerException occurs when you attempt to call `null.something()` and the LogCat clearly says the NPE comes from this line. I'm sorry but `activity` is `null`, this is the _only_ possibility.

Comment: Can you put `if (activity != null)` before you execute the line 121 and see if it throws null pointer exception again? We can all assure you that your activity is null in this line...

Comment: I concede that it's null.  The short of it is that I got confused with another project fragment that is "identical" to the one I am working in - Mea Cupla!  Thank you for all your patience!!!

Comment: Good stuff :) Glad you have the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [Android Advanced Training: Managing Network Usage, Check a Device's Network Connection](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html).  It is a good tutorial on how to properly check the network state of an Android device.

Inside, you'll find a way to more generally query the network state and then in particular, you can check if the user is on WiFi or not.

The relevant code:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
```

The relevant permissions:

```
android.permission.INTERNET - Allows applications to open network sockets.
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE - Allows applications to access information about networks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Repalce `activity` in your code above by your activity name, or just remove it if you are within the activity.

Comment: This is in a fragment and the activity is a reference to the host activity.

Comment: If you are getting a null pointer exception in this line, then activity has the value `null`. Check whether activity has been properly initialized.

Comment: activity is initialized without question.  When I comment out the wifi line, the callback function in the host activity gets called just fine.